# Ошибка при сборке libvpx под mingw-w64

Tags: mingw, сборка, libvpx, mingw-w64

Решил пересобрать libvpx, при сборке в консоли MINGW32 выдаёт ошибку:

```
In file included from vpx/src/vpx_codec.c:19:0:
vpx/src/vpx_codec.c: In function 'vpx_codec_version':
./vpx_version.h:6:39: error: expected expression before '<<' token
 #define VERSION_PACKED ((VERSION_MAJOR<<16)|(VERSION_MINOR<<8)|(VERSION_PATCH))
                                       ^
vpx/src/vpx_codec.c:23:38: note: in expansion of macro 'VERSION_PACKED'
 int vpx_codec_version(void) { return VERSION_PACKED; }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./vpx_version.h:6:59: error: expected expression before '<<' token
 #define VERSION_PACKED ((VERSION_MAJOR<<16)|(VERSION_MINOR<<8)|(VERSION_PATCH))
                                                           ^
vpx/src/vpx_codec.c:23:38: note: in expansion of macro 'VERSION_PACKED'
 int vpx_codec_version(void) { return VERSION_PACKED; }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./vpx_version.h:6:78: error: expected expression before ')' token
 #define VERSION_PACKED ((VERSION_MAJOR<<16)|(VERSION_MINOR<<8)|(VERSION_PATCH))
                                                                              ^
vpx/src/vpx_codec.c:23:38: note: in expansion of macro 'VERSION_PACKED'
 int vpx_codec_version(void) { return VERSION_PACKED; }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./vpx_version.h:6:78: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 #define VERSION_PACKED ((VERSION_MAJOR<<16)|(VERSION_MINOR<<8)|(VERSION_PATCH))
                                                                              ^
vpx/src/vpx_codec.c:23:38: note: in expansion of macro 'VERSION_PACKED'
 int vpx_codec_version(void) { return VERSION_PACKED; }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:157: vpx/src/vpx_codec.c.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** [Makefile:17: .DEFAULT] Ошибка 2
```

Порядок команд:
cd /d/Projects/Libraries/src/libvpx-master
./configure --prefix=out --enable-static --target=x86-win32-gcc
make

Всё, дальше ошибка.

После `./configure` в vpx_version.h переменные определены без значений:

```
// This file is generated. Do not edit.
#define VERSION_MAJOR  
#define VERSION_MINOR  
#define VERSION_PATCH  
#define VERSION_EXTRA  ""
#define VERSION_PACKED ((VERSION_MAJOR<<16)|(VERSION_MINOR<<8)|(VERSION_PATCH))
#define VERSION_STRING_NOSP ""
#define VERSION_STRING      " "
```

**Что не так? Неужели надо править гугловские исходники???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня никаких ошибок при сборке не возникает.

Делаю так:

```
cd ~
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx
mkdir build
cd build
../libvpx/configure --disable-examples --disable-install-docs --disable-unit-tests --disable-shared --enable-static --target=x86-win32-gcc
```

Выдаёт:

```
  disabling examples
  disabling install_docs
  disabling unit_tests
  disabling shared
  enabling vp8_encoder
  enabling vp8_decoder
  enabling vp9_encoder
  enabling vp9_decoder
Configuring for target 'x86-win32-gcc'
  enabling x86
  enabling runtime_cpu_detect
  enabling mmx
  enabling sse
  enabling sse2
  enabling sse3
  enabling ssse3
  enabling sse4_1
  enabling avx
  enabling avx2
  enabling avx512
  using yasm
  enabling postproc
  enabling webm_io
  enabling libyuv
Creating makefiles for x86-win32-gcc libs
Creating makefiles for x86-win32-gcc tools
Creating makefiles for x86-win32-gcc docs
```

Далее, если выполнить `make`, успешно происходит сборка.

В файле `vpx_version.h` оказывается такое содержимое:

```
// This file is generated. Do not edit.
#define VERSION_MAJOR  1
#define VERSION_MINOR  6
#define VERSION_PATCH  1
#define VERSION_EXTRA  "1474-g8a4336ed2"
#define VERSION_PACKED ((VERSION_MAJOR<<16)|(VERSION_MINOR<<8)|(VERSION_PATCH))
#define VERSION_STRING_NOSP "v1.6.1-1474-g8a4336ed2"
#define VERSION_STRING      " v1.6.1-1474-g8a4336ed2"
```

Но этот файл появляется не после команды `../libvpx/configure`, а в процессе выполнения команды `make`.

Comment: Поделитесь пожалуйста, как устанавливали MSYS2 / MinGW, какие пакеты ставили... Просто я всё сделал как у Вас, но `VP8_COMMON {aka struct VP8Common}' has no member named 'postproc_state'` - и всё, до `install` дело не дошло...

Comment: @Iceman Ставил вот по [этой](https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2) инструкции. Дополнительно поставил только `yasm`. Для компиляции запускал консоль `mingw32.exe`.

Comment: Нет, тоже самое. У меня при конфигурации появляется `Creating makefiles for x86-win32-gcc examples`, не смотря на `--disable-examples`. Может из-за этого... И вообще куча warning-ов при сборке, типа `warning: "CONFIG_VP9_HIGHBITDEPTH" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]`. Может как-то влиять на сборку процессор (имею ввиду всякие там наборы инструкций, "возраст" процессора)? Собираю на ноуте с Core i3-3217U

Comment: @Iceman У меня Core 2 Duo E8400.

Comment: А версия msys 32 бита или 64?

Comment: @Iceman 32-х битная.

Comment: Блин, всё оказалось совсем просто, аж до смеха - `pacman -Ss libvpx` и после - `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-libvpx`

Comment: @Iceman Только это не имеет никакого отношения к сборке из сорцов.